# Computer will not go to sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep

When I tell my Windows 10 computer to go to sleep, it immediately wakes back up. Usually I just have to do this 3-4 times and it finally goes to sleep until I wake it back up, but now I've put it to sleep about 20 times, rebooted, etc. and nothing has worked. I've run `powercfg -lastwake` and these are the results every time:

```
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 1
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Device
    Instance Path: USB\VID_05AC&PID_024F\8&2d93c62f&0&2
    Friendly Name:
    Description: USB Composite Device
    Manufacturer: (Standard USB Host Controller)
```

This device has no "Allow this deice to wake PC" setting, and just outright disabling it disables my USB ports. I've tried making sure there is nothing plugged in except for my mouse and keyboard, and I've tried using all the different ports available. I'm at a loss of what to do at this point. Just shutting down my computer every time I want to put it to sleep is not an option, because it's very hard to get to the power button every time I want to turn it on, plus I'd rather not spend most of my day waiting for my computer to start back up, opening all the applications etc.

Update: I have since upgraded my computer to a new motherboard, RAM, and CPU (switching from intel to AMD). In the process, I also did a clean install of Windows 10, 21H1. The issue still occurs, though now if the computer finally does go to sleep, the computer will occasionally turn back on a few hours later. The only components that are shared are the GPU, SSD, and PSU.

Comment: Go to BIOS and look there for Wake on LAN or or Wake setup in BIOS and disable these. That may work for you

Comment: @John I've never had those enabled.

Answer (score -2):

Use a command prompt and `powercfg /lastwake` to figure out what's causing the machine to wake from sleep. Then you can turn it off in the device's settings.

There is more detail in this article: [How to find out why your PC wakes up, and how to stop it](https://www.ghacks.net/2013/12/31/find-pc-wakes-stop/)

Comment: You should quote the relevant information from your reference link.  An answer should be more then just a link to an external resource.  Please take note of the fact the author already tried `powercfg /lastwake` and indicated they got the same results.  The author is looking for **specific advice** on how to determine the reason their device is unable to go into S3 mode.  **In the case of the author a USB device is preventing the device from enter S3 mode.**

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm not sure how I missed that they had already used `powercfg`; I could have sworn that detail was not in the initial question but then there's no edit tag on it, so I have to assume that it was there all along and I simply missed it in a hurry to answer.